# Access MBean exposed by application from WebSphere Administration Console

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jmx

I need some configuration parameters in my Java EE application that can be monitored and updated in runtime. I decide that having JMX MBean in my app is a good solution for this. My application is deployed into WebSphere AS and I'm wondering will my custom MBean be accessible from WebSphere Administration Console (Web) in order to have a single access point to all administrative tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no feature in WebSphere's admin console to access custom MBeans.